# Xamarin Forms Array in Listview

Tags: arrays, sqlite, listview, xamarin.forms, json.net

i recently created a question on stackoverflow but updated the whole question, so i thought it would be better to create a new question.
When i want to create a ticket the array is not parsed, how do i get this to work with a SQLite database as well as JSON Newtonsoft?
When I create the ticket I get the error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "[]" to type 'System.String[]'. Path 'ticket.notes', line 1, position 170.'

When i open the ticket page (which also contains notes) i get a sqlite error:
System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know how to read System.String[]'.

Ticket.cs the model

```
    public class Ticket
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int pkid { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string ticketNumber { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string[] notes { get; set; }
        public DateTime closed { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    }
```

GeneralPage.cs (general tickets) creates tickets and send it to the API

```
public async void GeneralButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Wertzuweisung
            General g = new General();
            g.manufacturer = ManufacturerInfo.Text;
            g.model = ModelInfo.Text;
            g.subject = SubjectInfo.Text;
            g.description = DescriptionInfo.Text;

            //Verbindungsaufbau
            var url = "https://.../api/ticket/create";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuthenticationToken", "ExampleToken");
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { g.manufacturer, g.model, g.subject, g.description });
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            //prüft ob alle Felder ausgefüllt sind + Internetverbindung besteht
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //response initalisieren
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Api api = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Api>(responseBody);

                //Ticket speichern in Datenbank
                await App.Database.SaveTicket(new Ticket
                {
                    pkid = 1,
                    id = api.ticket.id,
                    ticketNumber = api.ticket.ticketNumber,
                    status = api.ticket.status,
                    subject = api.ticket.subject,
                    description = api.ticket.description,
                    notes = api.ticket.notes
                });
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Das Ticket wurde erfolgreich erstellt.", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Die Verbindung ist fehlgeschlagen füllen Sie alle Felder aus und prüfen Sie Ihre Internetverbindung.", "Ok");
            }
        }
```

TicketPage.xaml a listview with open tickets, where the array needs to be displayed (notes)

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,5,10,5">
                <!-- <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference TicketPageTest}, Path=IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference TicketPageTest}, Path=IsBusy}" Color="#1690F4"/> -->
                <ListView x:Name="ListViewTicket" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="None" SeparatorVisibility="None" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label>
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                        <Span Text="ID: " FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                                        <Span Text="{Binding pkid}" FontSize="18"/>
                                                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <!-- <Label Text="{Binding id}" FontSize="18" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/> -->
                                        <Label>
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                        <Span Text="Ticketnummer: " FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                                        <Span Text="{Binding ticketNumber}" FontSize="18"/>
                                                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label>
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                        <Span Text="Status: " FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                                        <Span Text="{Binding status}" FontSize="18"/>
                                                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="3" Color="Gray"/>
                                        <Label Text="Betreff" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding subject}" FontSize="18" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                                        <Label TextType="Html" Text="{Binding description}" FontSize="12"/>
                                        <Label Text="Notiz" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding notes[]}" FontSize="18" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: there are at least three different issues here: 1) saving the data to the db, 2) serializing/deserializing to/from the API, 3) displaying in the UI.  Please pick one to focus on.

Comment: i need some help with the serializing/deserializing because i always get a convert error. As i read sqlite cant save arrays into the db, so how can i manage this?

Comment: then it would be a good idea to focus your question on the json error.  Post the json you are working with, the class you are using to model it, and any error messages.  All the other stuff is a distraction.  Once you fix the json error, then move on to the next issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to attach the Json data here , it's helpful to debug what's going wrong.

And also tell us which line causes the error would be helpful .

The error seems the property `notes` in class `Ticket` takes the wrong type , it should be an array of `object` not `string`, try to change it to `object[]`.

You can use json2csharp(website) to create the model class to match the json data.